# Coloring blind spot case with alternate table row colors

Tags: tables, color

Enthusiastically using the alternate table row coloring feature in `xcolor` (which I discovered here on TeXSE, as many more most useful things), I stumbled on an annoying phenomenon: the code

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
left head&right head\\
\hline
\hline
cell&cell\\
\hline
L\hfill R&cell\\
\hline
cell&cell\\
\hline
cell&cell\\
cell&cell
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

That annoying blind spot is, doubtlessly, caused by the `\hfill`, but why? Can I get rid of it? I don't mind splitting that particular cell into two if you tell me how. Making extra column is not an option since I only need it occasionally in very few cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If you use `fill` glue the total must be `0fill` see the paragraph at the top of page 10 of `texdoc colortbl`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
left head&right head\\
\hline
\hline
cell&cell\\
\hline
L\hfill R\hspace{-\fill}\mbox{}&cell\\
\hline
cell&cell\\
\hline
cell&cell\\
cell&cell
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

You will have a perfect ouput in the PDF viewers. The rules won't seem to vanish in some PDF viewers (such as Adobe Reader) as some levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l|r}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{}
\Body
left head&right head\\
\hline
\hline
cell&cell\\
\hline
L \Block[r]{}{R}&cell\\
\hline
cell&cell\\
\hline
cell&cell\\
cell&cell
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

Try to put

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}L&R\end{tabular}
```

Instead of the cell with `\hfill` (you can build a macro easily)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (Except I changed it to `...@{}lr@{}...`)

Comment: Umm not *entirely* perfect though - it does not stretch across the cell properly: with `\hfill` the second entry was right aligned.

Comment: Obviously, @david-carlisle answer is right! Nice trick

Comment: I agree. Sorry, have to accept that one.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე obviously! No problem!